# Script reading files in ftp directory but not downloading them

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, download, ftp

The script below is able to read the files in the ftp directory file however it does not download them. I know they read them because the outputted list in the command window shows them.

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os, sys, os.path

def handleDownload(block):
    file.write(block)

ddir='U:/Test Folder'
os.chdir(ddir)
ftp = FTP('sidads.colorado.edu')
ftp.login()

print ('Logging in.')
directory = '/pub/DATASETS/NOAA/G02158/unmasked/2012/04_Apr/'

print ('Changing to ' + directory)
ftp.cwd(directory)
ftp.retrlines('LIST')

print ('Accessing files')

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
     for file in files:
        full_fname = os.path.join(root, fname);
        print ('Opening local file ')
         ftp.retrbinary('RETR U:/Test Folder' + fname,
                       handleDownload,
                       open(full_fname, 'wb'));
         print ('Closing file ' + filename)
         file.close();
ftp.close()
```

Comment: sorry but 1 indentation is incorrect, and 2) you're doing `file.close()` on a `file` which is a string object, and 3) you're listing the local files and write the contents of the remote files in it? so your local files must exist prior to download eponymous files on the server? that's not logical.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can do this using the `pysftp` library:

```
import pysftp

with pysftp.Connection('hostname', username='username', password='password') as sftp:
    ftp_files = sftp.listdir('/ftp/dir/')

    for file in ftp_files:
        sftp.get(os.path.join('/ftp/dir/', file), localpath=os.path.join('/path/to/save/file/locally/', file))
```